# Can't import models to celery tasks.py file

Tags: django, celery, importerror

in my tasks.py file I want to import models from polls app, but I get **django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet** when starting the worker

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys ,os
from polls.models import User
from .celery import app


@app.task
def add_user(user):
    # for user in users:
    print('urra')
    #user = User(user.first_name, user.last_name, user.email)
    # user.save()
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os, sys
from task import celery_config
import dotenv
from os.path import dirname, join

app = Celery('task',
             broker='amqp://root:lusine_admin@localhost/task',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['task.tasks'])

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "task.settings")
app.config_from_object(celery_config)
# app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Actaually I got error polls module not found, but then from bash I added it to pythonpath and know I get this error.

Comment: share your full trace back please.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is with your config.  If you want to connect celery with your django, you have to [initialize the celery config from the django settings](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django).  In your celery.py replace this line:

```
app.config_from_object(celery_config)
```

with

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```